# understanding PLINQ bottleneck in tree search

Tags: c#, plinq, alpha-beta-pruning

I'm having some strange results with PLINQ that I can't seem to explain.  I've been trying to parallelize an Alpha Beta tree search to speed up the search process, but it is effectively slowing it down.  I'd expect as I raise the degree of parallelism, I'd linearly increase nodes per second... and take a hit with additional nodes processed as pruning is pushed off until later.  While the node count matches expectation, my times don't:

non-plinq,
nodes visited: 61418,
runtime: 0:00.67

degree of parallelism: 1,
nodes visited: 61418,
runtime: 0:01.48

degree of parallelism: 2,
nodes visited: 75504,
runtime: 0:10.08

degree of parallelism: 4,
nodes visited: 95664,
runtime: 1:51.98

degree of parallelism: 8,
nodes visited: 108148,
runtime: 1:48.94

---

Anyone help me with identifying the likely culprits?

relevant code:

```
    public int AlphaBeta(IPosition position, AlphaBetaCutoff parent, int depthleft)
    {
        if (parent.Cutoff) 
            return parent.Beta;

        if (depthleft == 0) 
            return Quiesce(position, parent);

        var moves = position.Mover.GetMoves().ToList();

        if (!moves.Any(m => true))
            return position.Scorer.Score();

        //Young Brothers Wait Concept...
        var first = ProcessScore(moves.First(), parent, depthleft);
        if(first >= parent.Beta)
        {
            parent.Cutoff = true;
            return parent.BestScore;
        }

        //Now parallelize the rest...
        if (moves.Skip(1)
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
            .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
            .Select(m => ProcessScore(m, parent, depthleft))
            .Any(score => parent.BestScore >= parent.Beta))
        {
            parent.Cutoff = true;
            return parent.BestScore;
        }
        return parent.BestScore;
    }

    private int ProcessScore(IMove move, AlphaBetaCutoff parent, int depthleft)
    {
        var child = ABFactory.Create(parent);
        if (parent.Cutoff)
        {
            return parent.BestScore;
        }
        var score = -AlphaBeta(move.MakeMove(), child, depthleft - 1);
        parent.Alpha = score;
        parent.BestScore = score;
        if (score >= parent.Beta)
        {
            parent.Cutoff = true;
        }
        return score;
    }
```

And then the data structure for sharing Alpha Beta parameters across levels of the tree...

```
public class AlphaBetaCutoff
{
    public AlphaBetaCutoff Parent { get; set; }

    private bool _cutoff;
    public bool Cutoff
    {
        get
        {
            return _cutoff || (Parent != null && Parent.Cutoff);
        }
        set
        {
            _cutoff = value;
        }
    }

    private readonly object _alphaLock = new object();
    private int _alpha = -10000;
    public int Alpha
    {
        get
        {
            if (Parent == null) return _alpha;
            return Math.Max(-Parent.Beta, _alpha);
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_alphaLock)
            {
                _alpha = Math.Max(_alpha, value);
            }
        }
    }

    private int _beta = 10000;
    public int Beta
    {
        get
        {
            if (Parent == null) return _beta;
            return -Parent.Alpha;
        }
        set
        {
            _beta = value;
        }
    }

    private readonly object _bestScoreLock = new object();
    private int _bestScore = -10000;
    public int BestScore
    {
        get
        {
            return _bestScore;
        }
        set
        {
            lock (_bestScoreLock)
            {
                _bestScore = Math.Max(_bestScore, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2008/01/31/7357135.aspx
has some interesting notes that might be useful for my problem...

Answer (score 0):

When you do only very little work and setoff new threads for all underlying nodes you create a huge overhead on threading. You  are probably processing more nodes because of the Any, normally the processing whould stop, but some nodes have started processing before Any (the first match) was found. Parallelism will better work when you have a known set of large underlying workloads. You can try what happens if you only do parallelism at your top level node(s).

Comment: So there were less than twice as many nodes as optimal visited when doing 8 degrees of freedom... (by my count) but the time difference from doing 2 way parallel to 8 way parallel jumps from 10 seconds to almost 2 minutes... 

Unless all the overhead comes from PLINQ scheduling all the nodes in the enumerable, but only executing a few of them, that explanation doesn't hold water for me.